# Use \multicolumn for an array with a defined size

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have a table with the length and width of each column already defined.
I just need to use \multicolumn and still keep the lenght and width.
When I tried it i obtained an error so I don't how exactly to write it.

The table must have the width of the page or a little bit smaller that is why I use \parbox.

[image: This what my table should look like]

This is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array,multirow,colortbl}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
\arrayrulecolor{white}%
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
\hline
\parbox[c][0.28in][c]{2.9in}{\smallskip\centering\textbf{Component}} & 
\parbox\multicolumn{2}{c}[0.28in]{2.9in}{\smallskip\centering\textbf{Component equations}}\\ \hline

\parbox[c][0.64in][c]{3in}{\centering{Resistance}} &
\parbox[c][0.64in][c]{3in}{\centering{ U_{R}(t) = R\cdot i_{R} (t) }} &
\parbox[c][0.64in][c]{3in}{\centering{U_{R}(t) = R\cdot i_{R}(t) }}\\ \hline 

\end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Your code use no `\multirow`.

Comment: Sorry I meant `\multicolumn`. I edited my question

Comment: Do you really need to fix the height of each \parbox?

Comment: Yes my table is longer than that and I need the height to be large

Comment: `\parbox\multicolumn` ???

Comment: It would be much simpler to just use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{Component}` and arrange the height elsewhere eg end the row with `\\[.5in]`  why use parbox for single line entries?

Comment: I don't know how.. can you tell me how to do it elsewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

It was hard to see the intended layout as there were unrelated errors (eg the equations need to be in math mode) but I can not see why you need `\parboxes` here at all, something like this is I think the intended layout with much simpler markup.

[image]

Two versions, one set natural width, one with column widths specified.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array,multirow,colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
\arrayrulecolor{white}%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5}%
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
\hline
\textbf{Component} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Component equations}}\\ \hline

Resistance &
$ U_{R}(t) = R\dot i_{R} (t)$ &
$U_{R}(t) = R\dot i_{R}(t) $\\ \hline 

\end{tabular}%
}
\end{center}

\hrule

\begin{center}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
\arrayrulecolor{white}%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5}%
\begin{tabular}{| wc{3.5cm} | wc{5cm} | wc{5cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{Component} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Component equations}}\\ \hline

Resistance &
$ U_{R}(t) = R\dot i_{R} (t)$ &
$U_{R}(t) = R\dot i_{R}(t) $\\ \hline 

\end{tabular}%
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The table must have the width of the page or a little bit smaller that is why I use `\parbox`
I added a picture of my table done with Word

Comment: @Hailey You can specify the column widths by replacing `c` in the argument to `tabular` (a natural width centred column) by `wc{4cm}` a centred column of width 4cm or whatever widths you want. Look in a minute I will extend the answer

Comment: Thank you but it's still not like in my picture.. It is for my professor and he is verry demanding. the first row is less larger than the other rows

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `tabularx` in order to make sure the table is as wide as the textwidth, a custom column type in order to horizontally center the contents, `\rowcolors` (which is available when loading the `xcolor` package with the `tables` option to color the table background, `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}` to increase the visibility of the lines and the `cellspace` package in order to add some space above and below the contents of each cell:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{1.5\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X,C}
\begin{document}


\arrayrulecolor{white}
\rowcolors{1}{lightgray}{lightgray}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{0{C} | >{\(}0{C}<{\)} | >{\(}0{C}<{\)} }
\textbf{Component} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Component equations}}\\ \hline
Resistance &
U_{R}(t) = R\cdot i_{R} (t)  &
U_{R}(t) = R\cdot i_{R}(t) \\ 
\end{tabularx}




\end{document}
```